# Trouble getting power to Honeywell T9 from furnace

Tags: electrical, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

My previous, antique thermostat was only a two wire and we are trying to upgrade to a smart thermostat. I'm having trouble getting power through the green "C" wire though and I'm hoping my oil heating primary control is able to do it. I've got a Honeywell R7284 primary control and a Beckett ignitor...here's a link for the primary control: http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/085267336550_install.pdf

I've attached a picture of the wiring setup...and after research I tried both Red, White, Green and White, Red, Green for the T, T3 and 2 slots.

Will this setup provide power for the C wire? Thanks in advance!

[image: wiring on oil heater]